# subclass variable using superclass method

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I am trying to reuse superclass code to manipulate objects in a subclass without passing the actual object.

1: Is that possible?

2: if i do pass objects as a method argument, am i only moving the pointer or will this result in significant IO and waste?

MyCode (simplified):

```
class data2 extends data1{}

class A
{
    data1 data;
    public A(){data= new data1();}

    void useData(){data.doSomething();}
}

Class B extends A
{
    data2 data;
    public B(){data=new data2();}

    void useData(){super.useData();data.doSomethingElseToo();}
}
```

My code fails as super.useData() tries to use A.data which has not been initialized. I want it to operate on the B.data variable

Comment: You should add a language tag, as that might influence any answer.

Comment: have added the language tag, thanks